# How to get Note info using GOVC comand?

Tags: vmware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K2Hy.png)
I need to get extra information about the templates in VMWare data-store
How to get 'Notes' value using GOVC?

Unfortunately output of 'vm.info -e' does contains it.
I found only -e flag for verbos output.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to my colleague.
The answer is
vm.info -json  | jq .VirtualMachines[].Summary.Config.Annotation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).